# Rotten eggs aroma from fermenting beer

Tags: aroma

my Vienna Lager apparently finished fermentation, I took some beer to measure the FG and I perceived a strong rotten eggs aroma coming from beer, I know it's common with some yeasts. The question I have is: is it ok to start cold condition (lagering)? Or I should keep fermenter around 13C for some days to get off the rotten eggs aroma?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which yeast are you using, would help with a better answer.

Comment: Ah, I remember my first lager, I walked down into the basement and thought "oh no, this can't be good...", but I just hung in there for a few more weeks and it turned out great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many lager yeasts throw off sulphur compounds during the ferment.  The key is to be patient and not rush the fermentation process.  If you have fermented at the right temp with the right amount of yeast, patience will reward you and the yeast will clean itself up.

That is also why there is an extended layering phase when using a lager yeast.  Its not just about cold crashing the beer.  Its about letting the lager yeast condition the beer and clean up all those off flavor compounds.

So be sure you've let fermentation go at 11-13C for a good couple weeks, maybe even three.  Then go ahead with your planned cold layering phase and let that beer go for at least a month.

Comment: I'll let the fermentation at 13C for more 2 weeks than start the lagering. Thanks!

Comment: Please let us know how this works.

Answer (score -4):

Sounds like a hydrogen sulfide problem, aerate the beer by splash racking it to another container and wait a few hours, if the smell persists try again. If you've done this four times and it still smells I'd dump it.

Comment: Why would you aerate finished beer?  MAYBE the smell will go away, but then you'll be dumping oxidized beer instead.

Comment: Why do you think you are supposed to aerate your wort before pitching yeast? the oxygen at the beginning of the process is helpful to prevent things like this from happening. Aerating is how you fix the rotten egg problem in wine, why would you aerate wine if you'd just end up with oxidized wine? Adding a tiny amount of oxygen to still fermenting wort isn't going to oxidize and ruin your beer.